# Simple PDO connection/prepare statement query

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having trouble getting this to work w/out getting "Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarks\index.php on line 5"

```
<?php

    function addBookmark($url, $conn){
        $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO entries (url) VALUES (:url)');
        $conn->execute(array(':url' => $url));
    }

    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=bookmarks;host=localhost', 'username', 'password');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        if(isset($_POST['bookmark'])) {
            addBookmark($_POST['bookmark'], $conn);
        }

        $results = $conn->query('select * from bookmarks.entries');

    } catch (exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

?>
```

I just started fooling around with PDO today so I don't have the best grasp on the concept. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Instead of setting exception mode *after* connecting, [set it at the time of connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858). Also, do not use try/catch to die error message. it's pointless and insecure

Comment: HTTP Error 500 is not an error itself but just a stub. You need to read the error log for the actual error. Most likely it wold be irrelevant to PDO

Comment: Thank you, checking the log, I'm getting " Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bookmarks\index.php on line 5"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function addBookmark($url, $conn){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO entries (url) VALUES (?)');
    $stmt->execute(array($url));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, completely forgot that the connection var doesn't handle the execute function.

Answer (score 2):

The connection string seems a bit wrong.

```
'mysql:bookmarks'
```

should also have a host; and `bookmarks` is what I think the database name!

```
'mysql:dbname=bookmarks;host=localhost'
```

---

```
$conn->prepare('INSERT INTO entries (url) VALUES (:url)');
$conn->execute(array(':url' => $url));
```

needs to be rewritten as follows:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO entries (url) VALUES (:url)');
$stmt->execute(array(':url' => $url));
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the connection parameters accordingly. I'm still, however, getting the error.

Comment: @TimAych As commented by *Pekka 웃* in your question; please show what errors you are receiving!

Comment: Yeah, edited the error into original post.. "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request."

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly, but the way i create connection string is

```
mysql:host=localhost;database=database
mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database
```

I dont know if there is any other workaround.  I forgot whether its database or dbname